# How does the mv command work with external drives?

Tags: macos, command-line, external-disk

On the same drive I assume it would change something like a FAT table to repoint to the location of files.

**Question**

When going to a different drive (maybe even partition) does the `mv` command first copy, then remove the old files - in order to prevent data loss if an exception occured ?

Comment: Note that `mv` itself doesn't know anything about filesystem internals like the FAT table on a FAT filesystem.  As the answers point out, it merely makes a `rename()` system call, and leaves it to the kernel to return success or failure.  The Unix/POSIX file API leaves all the VFS details to the kernel; the kernel itself is the only thing with drivers for HFS+, VFAT, NTFS, etc.  See [the POSIX `rename(2)` man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.htm) for how simple it is.

Answer (score 10):

macOS's **mv** is based on the BSD source code. You can find the source code to the mv command online. Using https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/bin/mv/mv.c as a reference, you can see that they do indeed first try to *rename* the file and then if it is crossing filesystems, it does a **cp** followed by a **rm**.

```
    /*
     * If rename fails because we're trying to cross devices, and
     * it's a regular file, do the copy internally; otherwise, use
     * cp and rm.
     */
    if (lstat(from, &sb)) {
        warn("%s", from);
        return (1);
    }
    return (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) ?
        fastcopy(from, to, &sb) : copy(from, to));
}
```

Comment: The  source code snippet you link to actually do not have something to do with the detecting a cross-filesystem move or actually doing a cp followed by a rm. It is only the comment that describes this behavior - the actual code for it is really before the comment. The code after the comment already assumes that it is a cross-device move, and determines whether the source is a regular file to be copied internally, or something else that is moved using calls to the external programs cp and mv.

Comment: @jksoegaard - Correct. I was highlighting the section of code from the linked source code that directly addressed the question being posed.

Comment: Well, the comment addresses the question. The code does not, as the relevant code is before the comment :-)

Comment: It looks like the code snippet given is the most relevant part. It is preceeded by `if (!rename(from, to)) { ... return (0); } if (errno == EXDIV) { ... } else { ... return (1); }`, which, if I'm reading it right, will exit in all scenarios except for those in which the rename fails due to cross-device links. The snippet given shows the methods used to copy in cross-device scenarios: A fast-copy (built into **mv**) if the source is a regular file, or execution of the **cp** binary followed by the **rm** binary otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that explanation in my answer above - however the snippet is not alone relevant if you want to look at code. The question was (1) what happens if it is on the same drive (the code before this snippet), and (2) what happens if it is on a different drive (the code after this snippet inside the fastcopy() function for regular files and copy() otherwise). Without knowing what’s inside those functions, the snippet here doesn’t make much sense. You could be led to believe that fastcopy() does a rename(), which it doesn’t.

Comment: @jksoegaard good point. The answer includes a reference to the rename attempt but doesn't clarify that the rename attempt isn't actually in the snippet, and doesn't distinguish `fastcopy` from `copy` or mention that they both copy and then delete (only `copy` actually executes `cp` and then `rm`). More clarification around that could be useful in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're right in thinking that moving a single file on the same file system is really just implemented as a rename operating that the file system structure is changed to update the new name/location of the file, but the file contents are not read/written to the drive again.

When the move happens across two different file systems (drives or partitions), then the `mv` commands first deletes the destination (if there were an old file there already), copies over the contents of the file to the destination and then finally removes the source file.

The behavior is explained in the manual for mv on macOS:

> As the rename(2) call does not work across file systems, mv uses cp(1) and rm(1) to accomplish the move.  The effect is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> rm -f destination_path && \
> cp -pRP source_file destination && \
> rm -rf source_file
> ```

In regards to the other answer that compares this behavior with the FreeBSD source code - the mv command on macOS is actually a bit different than on FreeBSD. In particular it makes sure that extended attributes and resource forks are moved over correctly and do not disappear when moving across file system boundaries.

You can read the [actual macOS source for `mv`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-272.220.1/mv/mv.c.auto.html).
You'll see that it is similar in structure as the FreeBSD version, but contains various Apple specific enhancement. In addition to the functionality regarding extended attributes and resource forks as described above, it also has performance enhancements for use with Xsan (distributed file system).

You'll find in the code that first a rename is attempted:

```c
if (!rename(from, to)) {
    if (vflg)
        printf("%s -> %s\n", from, to);
    return (0);
}
```

If this `rename()` fails, the code checks why it failed. Especially it checks for the error number EXDEV, which means that the rename would have crossed file systems, and thus cannot be done:

```c
if (errno == EXDEV) {
    struct statfs sfs;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    /* Can't mv(1) a mount point. */
    if (realpath(from, path) == NULL) {
        warnx("cannot resolve %s: %s", from, path);
        return (1);
    }
    if (!statfs(path, &sfs) && !strcmp(path, sfs.f_mntonname)) {
        warnx("cannot rename a mount point");
        return (1);
    }
} else {
    warn("rename %s to %s", from, to);
    return (1);
}
```

Note here that this code aborts the move in case that the source contains unresolvable symbolic links, or if it is actually a mount point - and also generally if the `rename()` fails for other reasons than EXDEV.

Only in case that `rename()` fails with error number EXDEV, and not for the above mentioned reasons, the following code is run:

```c
/*
 * If rename fails because we're trying to cross devices, and
 * it's a regular file, do the copy internally; otherwise, use
 * cp and rm.
 */
if (lstat(from, &sb)) {
    warn("%s", from);
    return (1);
}
return (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) ?
    fastcopy(from, to, &sb) : copy(from, to));
```

This code branches out to do the move between file systems in two different ways depending on whether or not the source to be moved is actually a regular file - or it is something else. "Something else" is usually a directory, a symbolic link, a device node or similar.

In case of a regular file, it uses `fastcopy()` which simply opens the source and destination files, `read()`s the data from the source and `write()`s them to the destination. Unlike the FreeBSD version, the `fastcopy()` function uses `fcopyfile()` to copy over ACLs and extended attributes from the source to the destination.

In case of something that is not a regular file, it simply spawns external commands to perform the move: `cp` for copying and `rm` for deleting.

Comment: This is a more verbose but much more descriptive answer than the current top-rated answer. From your description, it sounds like the simple answer to OP's question is **yes**, when working with cross-device moves `mv` does first copy and then delete the source file.